# In Apache NiFi processor is there a way to get the host's fqdn and IP address?

Tags: apache-nifi

In the InvokeHTTP processor I plan to submit the host and IP of the node thats making the HTTP request to the server as part of HTTP request header.

My question is, without hardcoding anything, is there a constant or a predefined name that I can use for these values?

I am on Apache NiFi 1.7.1 running on CentOS 7.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NiFi Expression Language has a hostname function that can return the fully qualified hostname:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#hostname

You could add a user-defined property to the config of InvokeHttp and set the value to ${hostname(true)} and then make sure to include that property name as one of the properties to send as a header.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, thats it. And for the IP Address I saw that there is the 'ip' function.